# How many edges does a complete graph with n nodes have?

Tags: graph-theory

I know the answer but i need a mathematical prove for it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: how many pairs you can chose out of $n$ points. that's an equivalent question. the answer is ${n \choose 2} $ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the $n$ nodes has $n-1$ edges emanating from it. However, $n(n-1)$ counts each edge twice.  So the final answer is $n(n-1)/2$.